# RESTful Webservices - Basic Auth in Spring MVC 3.x

Tags: rest, authentication, spring-mvc, basic-authentication, interceptor

We are developing RESTful webservices using Spring MVC 3.x. I am wondering what is the best way to implement Basic Auth. Note that we do not want to use Spring Security. We just want to use regular Basic Auth.

Each request should be authenticated. No state maintained. Its regular u/p authentication and the credentials are validated against the database.

- I was thinking of using `Interceptors`. So every request to the server will first go through    the interceptor. Is this the best practice?
- I am not sure about `filters`. Is this same as interceptors?
- Any other better way to implement this? What is industry standard for this implementation?
- What are the use cases for `interceptors` / `filters`, if these two are different?

Thoughts?
Thanks much!

Comment: I personally like the idea of using Spring Security.  This way, if you decided to change out the authentication later, you can.  Example of Basic Auth using Spring Security: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-http-basic-authentication-example/

Comment: Do you have any idea on Basic-Auth without Spring Security?

Comment: You would have to somehow process the HTTP headers manually.  You could use a Servlet Filter, or if you want to stick with Spring, an Interceptor.  Google for "spring interceptor vs servlet filter" for info on pros/cons.  Or, you could maybe use Apache WSS4J, but I have only used it for Soap web services, so I am not certain if you can do it with a RESTful service.  I don't like these solutions, however, as its sort of like vendor lock-in, as a custom solution will be much harder to replace later on down the road.